# GitHub Electron: build menu in required file

Tags: menu, require, electron

I am seasoned in JavaScript, but very new to node and to Electron. I am trying to piece the technique together from code samples and what documentation I can find.

I would like to include my menu code in a separate file. The main code is in a file called `renderer.js` and the menu code in one called `menu.js`. A simple example:

```
//  renderer.js
    function doit() {
        alert('hello'); 
    }


    module.exports.doit=doit;                       //  Added
    var q=require('./menu');

    var q=require('./menu');

//  menu.js
    var template = [
        {
            label: 'Test',
            submenu: [
                {
                    label: 'Something',
                    click() {
                        doit();
                    }
                }
            ]   
        }
    ];

    const {remote} = require('electron');
    const renderer=require('./renderer');           //  Added

    const {Menu, MenuItem} = remote;
    const app=remote.app;                           //  Addes
    const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(template);
    Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);
```

The menu is created, but when selecting the menu item, I get the message: `Uncaught ReferenceError: doit is not defined`.

I understand the meaning of the message, and clearly variables are not passed between the files.

How can I accomplish this?

**Update:** I have added some lines in the sample incorporate the accepted answer below. This now works.

Clearly I did not understand the meaning of `require()`. It strikes me as odd that each file can `require` the other. Anyway …

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you're doing `var q=require('./menu');` in `renderer.js`?

Comment: @VadimMacagon I don’t want to bloat the `rendered.js` code with the menu code, so I’ve separated it out. The `var q=` was for testing purposes which I forgot to remove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to access symbols defined in one Node module from another you have to export them via [`module.exports`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/modules.html#modules_module_exports):

```
// renderer.js
function doit() {
  // ...
}
module.exports.doit = doit;
```

And load the module via `require`:

```
// menu.js
const { doit } = require('./renderer');
// OR: const doit = require('./renderer').doit;

var template = [
    {
        label: 'Test',
        submenu: [
            {
                label: 'Something',
                click() {
                    doit();
                }
            }
        ]   
    }
];
```

This and much more is covered in the [Node API docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/modules.html).

Comment: This (nearly) does the job. I have incorporated your answer in my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to solve the same challenge. Currently I am looking into this:

https://github.com/ragingwind/electron-menu-loader

He basically adds a property 'event' and replaces that with an event handler.